# CasperJS can't open link.href

Tags: casperjs

I have a link button on the page:

```html
<a id="quote" href="quote.html" target="_blank">Quote</a>
```

At first I click the link:

```js
casper.thenClick('#quote');
```

But I can't capture the pop-up window. So I get the url of the link and open it in current window:

```js
var url = '';

function getQuoteStartUrl() {
    var link = document.querySelector('a#quote');
    return link.getAttribute('href');
}

casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
    this.echo(url);
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
```

The url is correct but the page is empty. Then I try this:

```js
var url = 'http://quote.html';

casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
    this.echo(url);
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
```

It works.
Finally I know why it doesn't work: It bind steps before the function call. So I try this:

```js
casper.then(function() {
    this.echo(url);
    this.thenOpen(url);
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
```

It works too.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try out the following?

```js
var url = '';

casper.then(function() {
    url = this.getElementAttribute('a#quote', 'href');
});

casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
    this.echo(url);
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
```

It looks as though you may not be setting the url before trying to load it.

Comment: Yes you're right, I move the argument to function, then it works.